# Error: Assigned data `value` must be compatible with existing data

Tags: r

i have dataset like this:

```
num  date
1    Na
2    09-12-2019
3    10-12-2019
4    NA
```

i am trying to convert na to 0 by that code :

```
newdata1<-newdata1 %>% replace(is.na(.), 0)`
```

But i got this error:

```
Error: Assigned data `value` must be compatible with existing data.
i Error occurred for column `prev_date`.
x Can't convert <double> to <datetime<UTC>>.
```

What should i do?

Comment: The error tells you that 0 isn't a date : the column type should be consistent. To use 0s with dates you could use character type.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like so in base R:

```r
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
df <- read.table(text = "
num  date
1    NA
2    09-12-2019
3    10-12-2019
4    NA
                 ", header = T)

df[is.na(df$date),] <- 0
df
#>   num       date
#> 1   0          0
#> 2   2 09-12-2019
#> 3   3 10-12-2019
#> 4   0          0
```

and with dplyr like so:

```
library(dplyr)
# with dplyr
df %>% 
  mutate(date = ifelse(is.na(date), 0, date))
#>   num       date
#> 1   0          0
#> 2   2 09-12-2019
#> 3   3 10-12-2019
#> 4   0          0
```

**EDIT**

I thought `Na` in your DF was a typo. Here is a solution, if not.
The first is in base R. It preserves the character class of `date`.

The second way uses dplyr and turns the `date` variable into a `date` - what it probably should be. As @Waldi already pointed out, there is no `date` like `0` and you probably have then to live with `NA` 's.

```r
df <- read.table(text = "
num  date
1    Na
2    09-12-2019
3    10-12-2019
4    NA
                 ", header = T)


df[is.na(df$date) | df$date == 'Na',]$date <- 0
df
#>   num       date
#> 1   1          0
#> 2   2 09-12-2019
#> 3   3 10-12-2019
#> 4   4          0

# but it looks like a date and it maybe should be date
# bring into form

df %>%
  mutate(date =as.Date(date,format = '%d-%m-%Y'))
#>   num       date
#> 1   1       <NA>
#> 2   2 2019-12-09
#> 3   3 2019-12-10
#> 4   4       <NA>
```

Comment: Works because `read.table` transformed the date to character, check `class(df$date)`, see my comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use something like this:

```
data$date[is.na(data$date)] <- 0
```